# De Rham Cohomology of the open ball on $\mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, homology-cohomology

I was recently in class and my professor suggested that one could compute the de Rham cohomology of the open unit ball in $\mathbb{R}^n$ in the following manner. 
Define the maps $f_{j-1}: \Omega^j(M) \to \Omega^{j-1}(M)$ for $j=1,\cdots , n$ with:
$$ \sigma = x^{k_1} dx^{k_2} \wedge \cdots \wedge dx^{k_j} - x^{k_2} dx^{k_1}\wedge dx^{k_3} \wedge \cdots \wedge dx^{k_j} + \cdots  $$
$$ \tau= g dx^{k_1} \wedge \cdots dx^{k_j}$$
Where we let:
$$(f_{j-1} \tau) = \left(\int_0^1 s^{j-1} g(sx) dx \right) \sigma$$
And it can be show that these have the property that:
$$ d \circ f_{j-1} + f_j \circ d = \mathrm{Id}  $$
Where $d$ is the exterior derivative. Could anyone provide a reference or explain to me how to proceed in using this to compute the de Rham cohomology?

Comment: Do you have access to Spivak's Calculus on Manifolds? He proved in the book Poincaré's lemma, which states that in a star-convex region of $\Bbb R^n$, closed forms are exact. So the de Rham cohomology are trivial.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose  that $\omega$ is a closed form, so that $d\omega=0$. Since $d\circ f+f\circ d=\mathrm{Id}$, we have $d(f(\omega))+f(d(\omega))=\omega$. Now $d(\omega)=0$, so this in fact tells us that $\omega=d(f(\omega))$ is exact, that is, it is in the image of $d$.

Comment: As for a reference: this should be explained in every textbook that treats de Rham cohomology.

Comment: Thanks for that, clears it up, so the de Rham cohomology of all degrees is necessarily zero?

Comment: Not in degree zero: there are no $(-1)$-forms

Comment: For sure, thank you.